# Insertar label dentro de panel

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, windows-forms

buen día comunidad.

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

Tengo un form en vb.net, dentro de este un panel y quiero colocar otros elementos dentro (como un label), pero cuando coloco un objeto y lo ubico con la propiedad location este queda por defecto atras del panel.
Como puedo conseguir que quede frente al panel?

```
    Dim width As Integer
    Dim height As Integer
    Dim panel As Panel
    Dim lbl As Label


    width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width
    height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height

    width = width * 0.8

    panel = New Panel
    panel.Size = New Size(width, 100)
    panel.Location = New Point(50, 10)
    panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
    panel.AccessibleName = "1"


    lbl = New Label
    lbl.Size = New Size(300, 100)
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 10)
    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(150, 150, 150)
    lbl.Text = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    lbl.TextAlign = 2
    lbl.Font = New Font(lbl.Font.Name, 30)
    Me.Controls.Add(panel)
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

Comment: Normalmente un panel tiene objetos hijos, y deberias agregarlos dentro de tu panel a cada label y otro componente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar tu `label` al panel, en tu código la estas agregando al formulario y no al panel que es lo que deseas, te coloco a continuación el sector de codigo con la corrección.

```
 panel = New Panel
    panel.Size = New Size(width, 100)
    panel.Location = New Point(50, 10)
    panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255)
    panel.AccessibleName = "1"


    lbl = New Label
    lbl.Size = New Size(300, 100)
    lbl.Location = New Point(50, 10)
    lbl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(150, 150, 150)
    lbl.Text = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    lbl.TextAlign = 2
    lbl.Font = New Font(lbl.Font.Name, 30)
    Me.Controls.Add(panel)

    //Me.Controls.Add(lbl) Reemplaza esta linea por la siguiente
    panel.Controls.Add(lbl)
```

Con este simple arreglo tu label se colocará dentro del panel.